# Building an Expression<Func<T,bool>> from string

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, linq-to-entities, expression

I have an `Expression<Func<T,bool>>` variable that use it for filtering a `Linq to entity` query:

```
Expression<Func<Person,bool>> predicate= new  Expression<Func<Person,bool>>();
predicate= t=>t.FirstName.Contains("A");
....
var result = _Context.Persons.Where(predicate).ToList();
```

I want the user could save his defined predicate as string in a file or database to use it in the next time.
so I save the predicate as `string`:

```
string str = predicate.ToString();
SaveToDb(str);
```

Is there any way to rebuild the `Expression<Func<T,bool>>` from saved `str`?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use the [Expression Tree Serializer](http://expressiontree.codeplex.com/) open source project. With this you can serialize and deserialize expression trees to store them in db or to send them to another component, and if required use the ToString method for debugging or report.